# Get id for popup resource menu item in c++ mfc vs2015

Tags: c++, winapi, localization, mfc, popup

I am in the process of localizing a mfc application. My approach has been to create an resource only dll which contains a translated copy of the gui. My problem is that there are places in the source code were popup resources are found by their string name. Since I've translated those strings into another language these functions do no longer work. My intended solution to this was to find these elements by ID instead, however when I tried this I found out that they do not appear to have a unique ID.

See below for snippet of the .rc file I am working with and note that the popup resource & Action do not have an id:

```
IDR_MAINFRAME MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "&Action"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&Tracking Start\tF2",         ID_TRACKING_START
        MENUITEM "Record...\tCtrl+R",           ID_RECORDING_STREAMTOFILE
        MENUITEM "Mouse Control Start\tF9",     ID_ACTION_MOUSECONTROL
        MENUITEM "Reflex Reduction\tF12",       ID_REFLEXREDUCTION_TOGGLE
        POPUP "Text &Log"
        BEGIN
            MENUITEM "Select Log&file...",          ID_LOGGING_FILE
            MENUITEM "Start &Logging\tF6",          ID_LOGGING_LOG
        END
        MENUITEM SEPARATOR
        MENUITEM "E&xit\tAlt+F4",               ID_APP_EXIT
    END
END
```

And a snippet below for the code which finds the UI element by string name

```
int CMainFrame::FindMenuItem(CMenu* Menu, LPCTSTR MenuString)
{
  ASSERT(Menu);
  ASSERT(::IsMenu(Menu->GetSafeHmenu()));

  int count = Menu->GetMenuItemCount();
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    CString str;
    if (Menu->GetMenuString(i, str, MF_BYPOSITION) && (strcmp(str, 
MenuString) == 0))
   {
     return i;
   }
 }
return -1;
}
```

After some googling I've found something called MENUEX https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/menuex-resource were it seems that you can add ID to popup resource elements. Again however when I tried to change the .rc file to use MENUEX instead of MENU my vs2015 compiler did not approve at all and now I am kind of stuck.

Thanks in advance for anyone who has any idea on how to solve my problem!

Comment: What about looking for popup menu by its first child MENUITEM ID?

Comment: Do you have a "strings" section in your resource DLL?  If so, you could make the comparison be against a translated string (either by making the caller responsible for loading the right string, or by changing the API to pass in a string ID, and then loading the string in the function.)

Comment: @MartinBonner this would work, but it's brittle, because if you change the name of the menu and you forget to change the corresponding string, your break the app. I think Alex F's idea is better.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to give an update and that I was able to solve my problem with with Alex F's idea. Thanks Alex! However I would like to add that I do not really find the solution that satisfying but I guess that is a problem with mfc.